# InputMismatch exception not working

Tags: java

I have created a program to check for input range for integer variable "paycategory" but when I want to check for inputmismatch errors as well. I tried it but its not working... I don't want to change the data type to string because the paycategory is supposed to be integer. Please help how to fix this problem ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.Object.*;

public class TestEmployeePayRoll {

     public static void main(String Args[])
     {
        String EmployeeID = null, FirstName = null, LastName = null, result;
        double HoursWorked;
        int PayCategory = 0, counter = 0;

      do
      {  
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try 
            {
            int flag = 1;
            String input1 ;
            System.out.println("Enter your Employee ID number: ");
            while(flag==1){

            EmployeeID = input.nextLine();

            if(EmployeeID.trim().length()>=5){
                    flag = 0;

                    System.out.println("Enter the First Name: ");
                    FirstName = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Enter Last Name: "+ " ");
                    LastName = input.nextLine();

            }else
            System.out.print("EmployeeID must be exactly 5 digits long: \n Enter the Employee ID again: ");
            }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
               System.out.println("Exception ");
            }

         try{


        do{
            System.out.println("Enter the Pay Category: "+ " ");
            PayCategory = input.nextInt();

        if(!(PayCategory >0 || PayCategory <5))throw new InputMismatchException();
        {
            System.out.println("Pay Category must be between 1 and 4");
        }
        }

        while(PayCategory < 1 || PayCategory > 4);
         }

         catch(InputMismatchException e)
         {
             System.out.println("PayCategory must be integers");

         } 
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of hours worked: ");
            HoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
            Double hours = new Double(HoursWorked);
            if(hours.isNaN())
        {
            System.out.println("---Enter a valid hours value---");
        }

            else if(!(HoursWorked >1 || HoursWorked <80))
        {
            System.out.println("---Enter value between 1 and 80---");
        }
        }

        while(HoursWorked < 1 || HoursWorked > 80);

        EmployeePayRoll obj1 = new EmployeePayRoll(FirstName, LastName, EmployeeID, HoursWorked, PayCategory);

        DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\n The pay details for:" + obj1.getName() + "\t\t\t" + "ID:" + EmployeeID);
        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Pay Category: \t\t\t" + obj1.getPayCategory());
        System.out.println("Hours Worked: \t\t\t" + obj1.getHoursWorked());
        System.out.println("Pay Rate: \t\t\t" + obj1.getPayRate());
        System.out.println("Gross Pay:  \t\t\t" + "$"+fmt.format(obj1.getGrossPay()));
        System.out.println("Tax Payable:  \t\t\t" + "$"+fmt.format(obj1.getTaxPayable()));
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t---------");
        System.out.println("Net Pay: \t\t\t" + "$" + fmt.format(obj1.getNetPay()));
        System.out.println("\n------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\n Process another employee? (Y/N)");
        result = input.next();

        }
            while (result.equals("Y")||result.equals("y"));

    }

 }
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not working"? What's it doing? What should it be doing?

Comment: its not doing anything bro....thats why I didn't put any detail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition below can never be true, so the `InputMismatchException` will never be thrown.

```
if(!(PayCategory >0 || PayCategory <5))
    throw new InputMismatchException();
```

Correct your condition.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

`!(PayCategory >0 || PayCategory <5)` is equivalent to `!(PayCategory>0) && !(PayCategory<5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Dogbane is quite correct in his answer but this problem is common in your code: you are over complicating your logical conditions which is making errors harder to spot.

Take the line:

```
  else if (!(HoursWorked > 1 || HoursWorked < 80))
```

HoursWorked will ALWAYS be either > 1 or < 80 so the bracketed condition will ALWAYS be true and the reverse never.  Try to make your logical conditions simpler so that you can easily see what they are rather than using the ! operator when it really isn't necessary.

This condition should be:

```
  else if (HoursWorked < 1 || HoursWorked > 80)
```